# Как вас зовут or как ваш зовут

Tags: притяжательные-местоимения

If вас = personal pronoun and ваш = possessive pronoun, isn't "your name" possessive?

Comment: Definitely "Как вас зовут?".

Answer (score 7):

**Зовут** doesn't mean *name* and isn't a noun. It's a verb that means *they call*. So basically, what you're asking is literally *How (как) you (вас) they call (зовут)?* or more idiomatically *What do they call you?* = *What's your name?*